# Cannot find python.h library in android ndk

Tags: python, android, c, kotlin, android-ndk

I am trying to interface a mobile application in android studio written in kotlin with a python algorithm.
I am using ndk to interface the kotlin code with the C code, but in the c code I am trying to interface it with the python algorithm by including python.h library but it displays the error:

```
 Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I am using Windows 10 and most suggested solutions were for linux.

Comment: Does Android come with python?

Comment: When do you get this error? Is it when you build the app on your desktop? Or is it when you run the app on a device?

Comment: @shawn no, android does not come with python by default. I think the common solution is to include the python runtime with your app.

Comment: @Shawn Well, I followed this link: [link](http://joaoventura.net/blog/2014/python-android-2/) which uses python in the C file that is linked to the java/kotlin part except that I get the above error due to the library. I couldn't find the library in the list of libraries that is listed in the program. Tried adding the path to the python itself in my PC in the local.properties file, it didn't work either.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The error occurs when building the app in the program.

Comment: You need to install the python development package. This is easy to do on Linux, but i don't know how to do it on Windows.